Solubility or reactivity of tantalum carbide and potassium polyselenides?
It is probably an unexplored system, but is there anything known about the low temperature thermodynamic equilibrium state of this?
By 'tantalum carbide', I mean $\ce{TaC}$, and by potassium polyselenides, any composition from $\ce{K2Se}$ to pure $\ce{Se}$.
Some useful properties include:

Equilibrium compositions at absolute zero temperature.
Coordination of each element in every phase present and on grain boundaries.
Formation enthalpies.
Densities.

Alternatively, if nothing can be said about any of the above, what are the most promising methods to study related phases?

Can chemical vapor deposition be done to mix the elements uniformly?
Which reliable computational models help with understanding?
Are there any related phase diagrams?


Low temperature? I'd be surprised if even molten selenide did anything to TaC.

But tantalum diselenide seems interesting.

It isn't about, if it does, but about the lowest energy configuration, which may be obtained indirectly using other precursors. @Mithoron

So I guessed, but how likely is, say, TaS2 + K2C2 to be thermodynamically favourable? Well, maybe potassium salts of selenoacids would be better, but still...

Still, it's interesting and I wouldn't mind being proven wrong ;)

@Mithoron I think, You mean $\ce{TaSe2}$ by TaS2... According to some approximate calculations provided here: https://oqmd.org/materials/composition/TaSe2 , large enough excess of selenium would form $\ce{TaSe2}$ and carbon preferred over $\ce{TaC}$ and $\ce{Se}$. For comparison with experimental value, only $\ce{TaC}$ is available on that site.
